# Does one establish an architecture?

Tags: word-usage

Was looking at my CV and wondered if this sentence is correct:

> Establishment and development of Microservices architecture and
>   department-wide web infrastructure services following department’s
>   architect guidelines & instructions.

The first part about "Establishing" or "Developing" an architecture sounds a bit off (English is my third language).

Explanation: "Microservices architecture" is a logical/abstract design pattern in Web Development, where you split your services into small, independent and single-purpose units that communicate with one another in order to provide a business service.

If more info needed, will gladly provide.

Comment: You gave a capital M, so  isn't "architecture" a part of the name, "Microservices Architecture"? Otherwise, you could comma or bracket off the part of the sentence which says what Microservices is/does.

Comment: Something like *introduction, implementation*, or *adoption* might work better. But I can't claim that *establishment* does not work at all.

Comment: "Establish" is a bit hard to map to actual actions. Did you do system design / architecture? Programming? Evangelizing? What did you do given micro-services were already in the guidelines? Apparently a recruiter spends an average of 6 seconds scanning your resume, so nuances in the language are far, far less important than convention. If it's a hands-on role, introducing things is less important than building. If you're looking for an architecture/management role, introducing things becomes important. "Establish" will get lost.

Comment: @jimm101 Very well. I will be applying for Development roles, so I guess you are correct. It's better to use a word that emphasizes the role I had done and the one I'm applying for. Thank you :)

Comment: 'Establishment' sounds very grandiose. Just like 'architecture'.

Comment: The _real_ ;) question is whether one establishes a microservice architecture or a microservice**s** architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not for hardware/software, I would have said *sculpt*, but here *developed* sounds better than *established*.